# jhipster - switch from undertow to tomcat

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

Currently I'm working on app using JHipster release v5.8.1
It has already configured Untertow and we have to switch it to Tomcat.

Can anybody help me with this process as I'm totally lost and really don't know how to do this? I want to avoid as much impact on the project as possible.

Comment: Try to replace `spring-boot-starter-undertow` to `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in your `pom.xml`

Comment: There are some explicit exclusions regarding the tomcat starter. In gradle e.g.     `configurations {
    providedRuntime
    implementation.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}` You must remove all exclusions to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using gradle, in the build.gadle file

1. delete the line `exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"`
2. delete also the line which includes undertow dependency
   `implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow"`

Springboot default embedded server is tomcat.
deleting this 2 lines make your app using default springboot configuration